# Discover number of CPU cores using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, cpu

I have an assignment in which i have to write a program in C on Linux(i use CentOS), which uses threads/processes to determine the number of cores from the CPU.
Firstly I tried to print the current time in mili/microseconds, because I know that there can run 1thread/core(or 2 with HT). But by miliseconds more than 10 threads printed the same amount of time and by microseconds none were identical.
Secondly I tried to measure the execution time of threads with clock, given I have 4 cores, the execution time of 4 threads at the same time should take almost as long as executing 1.But none of my programs could bring me closer to the number of CPU's.
Could you help me with some suggestions please?

Program printing current time:

```
pthread_t th[N];     

void* afis ()
{
    //time_t now;
    //time(&now);
    //printf("%s", ctime(&now));
    struct timeval start, end;
    long mtime, seconds, useconds;    

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    // usleep(2000);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    seconds  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
    useconds = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;

    mtime = seconds + useconds;

    printf("Thread with TID:%d   Elapsed time: %ld microsecons\n",(unsigned int)pthread_self(), mtime);
}     

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&th[i],NULL,afis,NULL);
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        pthread_join(th[i],NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program measuring processing time:

```
pthread_t th[N];    

void* func(void* arg)
{
    int x;
    int k;
    int n=(int)arg;
    for(k=0;k<10000000;k+=n)
    {
        x=0;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        clock_t start, end, total;
        start=clock();
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            printf("execution nr: %d\n",i);
            pthread_create(&th[j],NULL,func,(int*)i);
        }
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            pthread_join(th[j],NULL);
        }
        end=clock();
        printf("start = %ld, end = %ld\n", start, end);
        total=((double)(end-start) )/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("total=%ld\n",total);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added an idea in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should probably do is (in pseudo-code):

```
get the actual time (start time)
start 40 threads
    each busy for one second;
wait for all of them to stop
get the actual time (stop time)
```

If you analyze the time it took for the 40 threads to execute, you will know the number of cores, or at least you can make an assumption:

```
if the time was around 40s: you have one core
else if the time was around 20s: you have two
and so on
```

You could of course adapt the number of threads you start, aswell as the time you let them sleep, but I guess that if you sleep for a millisecond only you could get times that are not representative due to context switches and background tasks.

---

Instead of sleeping in the thread do something like:

```
highlyCpuIntensiveTask()
{
    //calculate something that takes up the time x (best would be above 1 second)
}
```

You execute it once without starting a thread, what would take up the time `x`. That time will be the reference time.

If, by adding more and more `pthread`s (`y`), executing the same function, you do not use up considerably more time than `x`, then you know that you do most probably have at least `y` cores. At some point, with `z` threads, the time will be around `2x`, at which point you'll know that you have `z-1` cores.

Comment: and how can I wait for all the threads to finish? if i use mutexes then only 1 thread will be able to access the function at a time, and with 4 cores it should be possible for 4 threads to acces it at once

Comment: ??  I would expect the time taken to be ~1 second, no matter how many threads you start, even on a single-core system.

Comment: @MartinJames you're totally right, one needs to busy wait of course. My bad.

Comment: The approach of "perform highly parallel computation and measure its speedup" is pretty general, and surely one can spend those cycles doing some interesting (maybe even useful) problem with good parallelism instead of busy-waiting.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved the problem creating a function checks if a number is prime from 1 to 100k(first with 1 thread, then with 2 and so on). I checked the execution time with "time ./program from the linux command line.And so i could determine how many cores my CPU is running on.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <unistd.h>

int number_of_cores = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
```

This is not portable, works only for Linux afaik.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is I am not allowed to interrogate the processor in any form, I need to determine it using threads/processes