# All threads are executing at once

Tags: multithreading, cpu, sleep

I try to find out the number of CPU cores using threads in C. Someone told me to try to execute 40 threads at once, make every thread sleep for one second, and see how many are executed simultaneously. I really like his approach, the problem is after executing my code, the program is sleeping for 1 second, and after that all threads are launced at once(no sleeping included).
Can someone please help me out?

```
void func(void* arg)
{
        int n=(int*)arg;
        sleep(1);
        printf("Exec nr:%d\n",n);
}


int main(void) {
    int i;
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    printf ( "Current local time and date: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
     pthread_create(&th[i],NULL,func,(int*)i);
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
    pthread_join(th[i],NULL);
    }

    time_t rawtime2;
    struct tm* timeinfo2;
    time ( &rawtime2 );
    timeinfo2 = localtime ( &rawtime2 );
    printf ( "Current local time and date: %s", asctime (timeinfo2) );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate (same user): [Discover number of CPU cores using threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258092/discover-number-of-cpu-cores-using-threads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able of discovering the number of CPUs in this way, because the scheduler may choose to run  all your threads on the same core and leave the other cores for (more important) stuff.
Therefore, you should rely on some functionality provided by your OS.
For example, on Linux the file /proc/cpuinfo provides information about the CPU. This file can be opened and parsed by any user-level program. Other operating systems provide different mechanisms.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions? I can use processes/threads but I can't interogate the CPU in any way

Comment: As I said, depending on your OS, there will be some mechanism. On which OS are you going to run the code ?

Comment: VirtualBox CentOS 6.5

Comment: So, it's Linux. Write a program which opens and parses the */proc/cpuinfo* file. Since string parsing is quite difficult in Linux, I suggest you to create an additional bash script that parses the file and returns the number of available cpus.